# What is this style of photo called?

Tags: effect

Is there a name for the type of editing applied to this photo?  It's similar to HDR but most HDR photos I've seen go overboard dramatic.  I don't consider the editing on this photo dramatic.

http://scontent-a-dfw.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfp1/t51.2885-15/10808791_301036443428025_1421790803_n.jpg

Also, is there a youtube tutorial that shows how to create this look?

Comment: Just looks like it's shot with a powerful flash. The sky has been darkened in post to add drama.

Comment: Are you really asking about the editing, or about the photograph overall?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fill flash + local contrast enhancement (there are many ways to do this, search for single image HDR).

The hard part is trying to compete with the ambient light so that your flash is not completely overpowered by it. you will either need multiple flash units to get enough light, or get your flash really close and rely on the inverse square law.

You will also need to use a high-speed-sync (pulsed) mode as you will need to shoot much faster than your camera's sync speed to freeze the action.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely not an HDR picture as intended as multiple exposures combined to a single image. But [tone mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_mapping) could have been used on the raw file, to enhance contrast and detail by using the large dynamic range of the raw.

As Elendil mentions, the use of a flash can be spotted by the cast shadow by the biker and the foreground grass and stones: they are not parallel, and the sunlight on the clouds suggests that the sun should be high in the sky.